# CSS border animation on hover

Tags: css, border, css-animations

So I've always animated with JavaScript but I wanted to try doing simpler animations with CSS. I have followed the guide on w3schools exactly but I can't seem to get any results.

```css
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
  margin: 0em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  animation: borderGrow 2s;
  -webkit-animation: borderGrow 2s;
}

@keyframes borderGrow {
  from { border-bottom: 0em solid #000; }
  to { border-bottom: 1em solid #000; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes borderGrow {
  from { border-bottom: 0em solid #000; }
  to { border-bottom: 1em solid #000; }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to work when you have no border setting on the element before animation. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/41vvqsfL/) works. I will add an answer if I manage to find out the reason. Also you can achieve this with transition itself instead of animations.

Comment: Oh really? Wow that's strange but it works, thank you very much. If you add it as an answer I'll vote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, the animation doesn't seem to work when the `border` property is not set on the original element itself (before the animation). Adding the `border` property to the original element does seem to solve it.

Based on [MDN's list of animatable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties), it seems like while the `border-color` and `border-width` are animatable, the `border-style` is not and this could possibly be the reason why we are having to add it in the original element. However adding just `border-style: solid` by default produces a border in almost all browsers (if not all) and so it is better to specify the `border-width: 0` also along with it.

> Note:
>
> 1. Behavior seems to be consistent in IE10, IE11 and Firefox. So it is more likely to be the expected behavior and not a bug.
> 2. I will update the answer with further details if and when I manage to find a clear and specific source explaining the reason for the behavior.

```css
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
  margin: 0em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 0em solid #000;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: borderGrow 2s;
  animation: borderGrow 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes borderGrow {
  from {
    border-bottom: 0em solid #000;
  }
  to {
    border-bottom: 1em solid #000;
  }
}
@keyframes borderGrow {
  from {
    border-bottom: 0em solid #000;
  }
  to {
    border-bottom: 1em solid #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Alternately this same effect can be achieved by just using `transition` instead of `animation` also. And for `transition` the need to set a `border` on the element before `hover` seems to be completely optional. Below is a sample snippet.

```css
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
  margin: 0em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 0em solid #000; /*optional for transition */
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 1s;
  transition: border-bottom 1s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1em solid #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough answer, you went above and beyond

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy: Always glad to be of help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1.
          You didn't complete `<a href="">...</a>` tag in html. Below this right code is....

```
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Problem 2. 
          You didn't add the primary border value for `a` tag. just add this css below to `nav ul li a`.

```
border-bottom:0em solid #000;
```

Check out my answer on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/r5dgrzwx/)

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have the same problem on Safari/Webkit Browser. The border property does not work when I use this on css animation keyframes. You have to set/declare first the border property on the css file in order to work.

Example:

```
    div.menu-menu-1-container ul li a, div.menu-menu-1-container ul.navbar-nav li.open ul.dropdown-menu li a,
.search-box .dropdown a i, .button-search
{
   border: 10px groove #ffd700; /* do not forget to declare the border property and value or it will not work; */
   animation: HHootteeLL 4s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: HHootteeLL 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: HHootteeLL 4s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: HHootteeLL 4s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: HHootteeLL 4s linear infinite;
}
```